# DAG runtime error with creating Airflow.cfg file

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error, airflow

First time creating a DAG. Each time I run within Pycharm, I get a FileExistsError [WinError 183], in addition to, an AirflowConfigException. Both errors describe how their attempts to create airflow.cfg failed because this file already exists within ~/airflow/airflow.cfg

How do I let the code know to use the existing cfg file? I read elsewhere this may be related to setting an AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Airflow using docker-compose. It will save you ton of headaches https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are multiple options here.

1. You can start airflow in the directory you have your `airflow.cfg` in. However this is strongly discouraged.
2. Before you start airflow, you run `export AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/your/airflow.cfg` followed by the command.
3. You can set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable in your bash or zsh profile. It depends on which terminal you use. This is the recommended way.